# I am not able to find enough properties from Get-AzADUser, is there any alternative to use complete properties?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

How to find disabled accounts through Azure Powershell?

I am trying find out the disabled accounts from our Azure Active Directory using get-AzureADuser cmd.
But it doesn't have any properties related to find disabled accounts.

Is there any alternative way to find it

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Get-AzureADUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureaduser)  which is part of [AzureAD module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0).

To  find out disabled accounts of user in Azure Active Directory below script will help,

```
   Get-AzureADUser -All $true -Filter 'accountEnabled eq false'
```

Comment: I am not able to all of users with Get-AzureADUser, From Get-AzADUser only works to get all users.But I am  not able to use filters in this command, is there any alternative way for this.

Comment: `Get-AzureADUser` part of command will  return all users in AAD. You need to use `Connect-AzureAD` command before using this command. If you are still facing any issue then please share how you are trying the cmdlet such that it helps me to correct the script.